# NSString Comparison is not working on iPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsstring

I'm getting this strange and simple issue when I try to compare two NSString in `if` condition. It works perfectly in case of iPhone but on iPad it didn't work.

I have four `UITextFields` and all have `delegate = self`. Upon `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` I'm returning `NO` and there is a call to the method as:

```
if (textField==self.dx1Field)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showDXViewForField:@"1"];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (textField==self.dx2Field)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showDXViewForField:@"2"];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (textField==self.dx3Field)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showDXViewForField:@"3"];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (textField==self.dx4Field)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showDXViewForField:@"4"];
        return NO;
    }
    else return YES;
```

The method `showDXViewForField` opens up another `ViewController` with `tableView` that shows some values from which user will select one and it is working perfectly fine.
I have made a delegate method which get the selected DX value and here I've applied the checks that if any of the four text fields have that value don't add it and show that it is already added.

```
-(void)getSelectedDX:(NSString*)dxName forField:(NSString *)fieldNumber
{

    if ([fieldNumber isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        if (self.dx2Field.text!=dxName&&self.dx3Field.text!=dxName&&self.dx4Field.text!=dxName) {
            self.dx1Field.text = dxName;
        }
        else
        {
            [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"This DX is already added!" duration:2.0f];
        }

    }
    else if ([fieldNumber isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@==%@",self.dx1Field.text,dxName);
        if (self.dx1Field.text!=dxName&&self.dx3Field.text!=dxName&&self.dx4Field.text!=dxName) {
            self.dx2Field.text = dxName;
        }
        else
        {
            [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"This DX is already added!" duration:2.0f];
        }
    } //and same for 3 and 4
```

The issue is that when I run it on iPAD is didn't work. It sets the duplicate value for text view but the same code runs on iPhone.

Comment: As David H answers is correct, and seems to be your issue, ask you this: Why did you do `self.dx1Field.text!=dxName` and `[fieldNumber isEqualToString:@"2"]`? You seem to want to do the same kind of test, but using to different ways. David H explained why, but that could have give you the hint on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing pointers, not values the pointers represent. All of your `self.dx1Field.text!=dxName` style comparisons should be using `isEqualToString`.

Comment: haha :D thanks! and I knew this thing... don't know what I was thinking!